# Calling a function from a string (key[:-1]())

Tags: python

Basically I have a list of key:items in a dictionary, and I am using a loop to find the key that matches the item I get, and I have functions for every key. The keys are numbered though, so I need to take off the last number.

This leaves me with needing to call a function from a string like the one in the subject:

```
key[-1]()
```

key[-1] actually is a string that returns something like scalcs, and that is the name of a function of mine that I then need to call.

I've searched around and have seen stuff about classes. I'm new and honestly have never worked with classes at all and have a lot of code and a lot of these functions. I would rather not do that method if at all possible.

```
d = {key1: item1, key2: item2, akey1: item3, akey2: item4, dkey1: item1, dkey2: item2}
```

I want to call key, akey, or dkey when my value matches that of the value attached to the key in the dictionary.

So I will loop through d like this:

```
        for key, value in d.items():
        if id == value:
            print key[:-1]
```

Now I just need to call that key[:-1]

Comment: "The keys are numbered though, so I need to take off the last number." - What do you mean by this sentence??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def hello_world():
    print "hello world"

d = {'hello':hello_world}

d['hello']()

locals()['hello_world']()
```

Comment: for key, value in snamedict.items():
            if id == value:
                globals()[key[:-1]]()

is returning: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: then try printing `globals()[key:-1]`  instead of calling it to see what is in it...

Comment: Dur, well that's one problem fixed but now am getting the correct function names but am getting the error:

KeyError: 'otof'

Comment: Perfect! So I had a couple problems. The original was because I was getting the wrong value, then one because I was calling the functions before I declared them(I think), and then finally because I was using global versus local. That fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to use `locals()` like this, because -- obviously -- it contains _all_ of your local variables, not just the important ones. This will cause weird and wonderful bugs. Instead, make a dictionary containing only the things you want, and use that.

Comment: I agree...  most definately ... but wanted to show how it works (Looks like hes actually using `globals()` which is no better)

Comment: I ended up using locals(). Anyways how do I use a dictionary and then still call them? I don't want to use locals anyways, but it won't let me call the function with a string otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the *name* of your function as key of your dictionary, you could try to store the function itself:

```
>>> f = lambda x:x+1
>>> g = lambda x:x-1
>>> D = {f:'0', g:'1'}
>>> (F,) = [k for k,v in D.items() if v=="0"]
>>> F(3)
4
```

If you need to keep your keys as strings, then create a second dictionary `(key_as_string, corresponding_function)` with all the correspondences and just retrieve the function corresponding to the key you got at the previous step.

---

Note that you need to be very careful that you don't have multiple keys with the same value, otherwise, there's no telling that you'll get a unique function. The safest way would be to build a reverse dictionary of what you have: `(some_string_index, a_function)`.

Note also that the function is just an object: in the example above, I used something very simple like a `lambda`, but you could use something far more complicated:

```
def a_function(...):
    ...

your_dictionary = {a_function: your_index}
safer_dictionary = {your_index: a_function}
```

Comment: Hey, the function is a multi-line function with a bunch of different if statements along with variables declared and etc, this wouldn't work right?

Comment: What if we have two values with '0'?? How will it be stored in (F,)??

Comment: @user1610719.. This is just a `lambda` function.. You can have any other ordinary multi-line function in place.. It would workk

Comment: @PierreGM.. I suspect, I didn't understand the OP's question correctly.. Need to take a look again..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question. Is the following right?

> You have dictionaries
>
> ```
> d1 = {key1: item1, key2: item2, ...}
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> d2 = {key1: function1, key2: function2, ...}
> ```
>
> Given an item `item2`, you want to find `function2`.

If that's it, then you should store the information you have differently, in the form

```
d = {item1: function1, item2: function2, ...}
```

The function you want is then `d[item2]`.

---

To generate `d` from `d1` and `d2`, you can do

```
d = {item: d2[key] for key, item in d1.items()}
```

Comment: Hey,
I have d = {key1: item1, key2: item2, akey1: item3, akey2: item4, dkey1: item1, dkey2: item2}

I want to call key, akey, or dkey when my value matches that of the value attached to the key in the dictionary.

Comment: So, when you have `item1`, what should you be calling? `key1`? `dkey1`?

Comment: item1 would call key(), item2 would also call key(). I got it fixed thanks to the help from Joran and also others obviously